# didUpdateToLocation called multiple

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have an iOS application witch uses the current location of the user. I am doing like this :

```
-(void)startGeoloc{

    NSLog(@"start geoloc");

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    AppDelegate *apDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    apDelegate.modeGeoloc = YES;
    [self callWebService:locationManager.location];

}
```

The problem of this, is that my method `callWebService:locationManager.location` is called twice  and i would like to call it just one time. how i can i do this ? thanks for your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

locationManager delegate methods can be called very frequently (they `didUpdateToLocation` all the time, right? :)

One way would be to have your `callWebService` have state, know whether it is currently executing a request and ignore concurrent requests if one is still going. Another way would be to keep a timestamp and only allow it through if 2 minutes has passed since the previous one.

Answer (score 11):

To ensure locationManager only calls the "didUpdate..." method once, use a BOOL to reference if the location has been found yet.

1. Create the ivar BOOL:

   ```
   @property BOOL didFindLocation;
   ```
2. Before locationManager startUpdatingLocation, set the new BOOL to NO. That way you can call for a new location update at will.

   ```
   -(void) startFindingLocation {

       self.didFindLocation = NO; // like this

       locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
       [locationManager setDelegate:self]
       [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];
       [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   }
   ```
3. In "didUpdateLocations", check for it.

   ```
   - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

       if (!self.didFindLocation) {
           self.didFindLocation = YES;
           [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

           // do the rest of your stuff

       }
   }
   ```

If possible, do not set didFindLocation anywhere else in your code to avoid confusion.

Comment: This is such a simple solution, can't believe I hadn't thought of it. Thanks!

Comment: ...to the BOOL-mobile!

Comment: This is a great answer, but be aware that the first time through didUpdateLocations might return old stored location data. Do some checks inside didUpdateLocations before accepting the location as valid and current, then set the didFindLocation bool. http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/02/detecting-bad-corelocation-data/

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

I think the easiest solution is setting the CLLocationManager to null.

```
locationManager = nil;
```

after calling

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 0):

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() fetch location continuously and didUpdateLocations method calls several times,
Just set the value for locationManager.distanceFilter value before calling locationManager.startUpdatingLocation().

As I set 100 meters(you can change as your requirement) working fine, and will work for you.

```
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 100
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```